# Distance from earth to another planet in solar system

Tags: orbital-mechanics

Initially I thought that the problem is trivial, but it turned out to be something relatively complex. I found no one place that would answer the question directly nor a quick guide showing what should be learned to find answer to the question how to calculate **current** distance from planet Earth to any other planet in the solar system.

I would approach this by finding orbital parameters of each planet in the solar system, then calculating current position of Earth and a planet in a virtual 3d grid. Then distance could be calculated as a distance between two points. However, orbital parameters do not indicate where the body was at a specified date and time to calculate current positioon (or does it?).

Anyways, I assume the approach may not be the best one, so could anyone guide me please through the steps what I should do to find out the answer? I am not asking for a detailed answer (but it is also extremely welcome), rather a quick guide with steps to perform.

Comment: Why don't you just ask JPL Horizons? https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/ If you want to do an approximate calculation yourself, see https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/planets/approx_pos.html

Comment: There are several popular ephemeris algorithms available that give the planet's in XYZ coordinates. VSOP87 is generally the most popular among amateurs: 
 https://github.com/gmiller123456/vsop87-multilang .  The more accurate one is JPL Development Ephemeris (many versions), and it's also common to use Kelperian elements for low precision: https://www.celestialprogramming.com/planets_with_keplers_equation.html .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Astropy](https://www.astropy.org/) if you want to quickly check your calculations:

```
from datetime import datetime
from astropy.time import Time
from astropy.coordinates import solar_system_ephemeris, get_body

now = Time(datetime.now())


def describe_coordinates(name, position, attrs=['ra', 'dec', 'distance']):
    print('  %s' % name)
    for attr in attrs:
        print('    %-8s : %s' % (attr, getattr(position, attr)))
    print()


with solar_system_ephemeris.set('builtin'):
    earth = get_body('earth', now)
    print('# At %s' % now)
    print()
    for body_name in solar_system_ephemeris.bodies:
        if body_name != 'earth':
            body = get_body(body_name, now)
            body_name = body_name.capitalize()
            print('## %s' % body_name)
            print()
            distance = earth.separation_3d(body)
            describe_coordinates('Geocentric', body)
            describe_coordinates('Heliocentric', body.hcrs)
            describe_coordinates('Heliocentric, cartesian', body.hcrs.cartesian, 'xyz')
            print('  Distance to Earth : %s' % distance)
            print()
            print()
```

It outputs:

```
# At 2023-04-27 09:44:53.778255

## Sun

  Geocentric
    ra       : 34d14m10.90835979s
    dec      : 13d42m21.46001395s
    distance : 1.0063943549757455 AU

  Heliocentric
    ra       : 106d14m27.87159228s
    dec      : 22d28m56.94074267s
    distance : 5.130514948556264e-08 AU

  Heliocentric, cartesian
    x        : -1.3258422804085509e-08 AU
    y        : 4.5513975699407177e-08 AU
    z        : 1.9619138730275765e-08 AU

  Distance to Earth : 1.0063943549757457 AU


## Moon

  Geocentric
    ra       : 124d48m02.39525773s
    dec      : 25d00m38.34773626s
    distance : 0.0026995142599885707 AU

  Heliocentric
    ra       : 214d05m54.6347582s
    dec      : -13d38m39.53898544s
    distance : 1.0061506676951295 AU

  Heliocentric, cartesian
    x        : -0.8096551559027314 AU
    y        : -0.548147038016342 AU
    z        : -0.23734472679499202 AU

  Distance to Earth : 0.002699514259988571 AU


## Mercury

  Geocentric
    ra       : 40d39m03.98386417s
    dec      : 17d43m37.96451338s
    distance : 0.5922967982014921 AU

  Heliocentric
    ra       : 205d38m53.37282051s
    dec      : -7d50m43.33450139s
    distance : 0.42581532038893316 AU

  Heliocentric, cartesian
    x        : -0.38026642171667674 AU
    y        : -0.18258630002004464 AU
    z        : -0.05812382160280432 AU

  Distance to Earth : 0.5922967982014921 AU


## Venus

  Geocentric
    ra       : 77d04m03.06478937s
    dec      : 25d11m50.50768648s
    distance : 1.0084230132455214 AU

  Heliocentric
    ra       : 150d41m16.70795145s
    dec      : 15d24m01.67653178s
    distance : 0.718625801083958 AU

  Heliocentric, cartesian
    x        : -0.6041178464130806 AU
    y        : 0.33918186973575504 AU
    z        : 0.19084110896591244 AU

  Distance to Earth : 1.0084230132455214 AU


## Earth-moon-barycenter

  Geocentric
    ra       : 120d30m00.75838748s
    dec      : 27d21m21.06357159s
    distance : 2.3979115366573416e-05 AU

  Heliocentric
    ra       : 214d14m26.21137691s
    dec      : -13d42m26.02630471s
    distance : 1.006390375351769 AU

  Heliocentric, cartesian
    x        : -0.808269742135427 AU
    y        : -0.5501375148644518 AU
    z        : -0.23847500138959987 AU

  Distance to Earth : 2.3979115366573416e-05 AU


## Mars

  Geocentric
    ra       : 108d21m31.74114144s
    dec      : 24d10m38.18627597s
    distance : 1.705887175958566 AU

  Heliocentric
    ra       : 144d28m48.65313552s
    dec      : 16d05m23.49287567s
    distance : 1.660391044142945 AU

  Heliocentric, cartesian
    x        : -1.2984791319650166 AU
    y        : 0.9268739921775513 AU
    z        : 0.4601684104176693 AU

  Distance to Earth : 1.705887175958566 AU


## Jupiter

  Geocentric
    ra       : 23d42m19.54748266s
    dec      : 8d44m48.66999627s
    distance : 5.935789547383545 AU

  Heliocentric
    ra       : 21d37m27.82704617s
    dec      : 7d42m28.28843327s
    distance : 4.953473431718855 AU

  Heliocentric, cartesian
    x        : 4.563240623775347 AU
    y        : 1.8089627548781806 AU
    z        : 0.6643702279109842 AU

  Distance to Earth : 5.935789547383545 AU


## Saturn

  Geocentric
    ra       : 337d10m28.78583463s
    dec      : -11d03m14.30536309s
    distance : 10.241761362879442 AU

  Heliocentric
    ra       : 332d15m03.21164734s
    dec      : -12d58m37.18881227s
    distance : 9.805931916932145 AU

  Heliocentric, cartesian
    x        : 8.45656099271295 AU
    y        : -4.449043850687695 AU
    z        : -2.2020185627492626 AU

  Distance to Earth : 10.24176136287944 AU


## Uranus

  Geocentric
    ra       : 45d31m37.96826473s
    dec      : 16d51m37.0661311s
    distance : 20.636385176873777 AU

  Heliocentric
    ra       : 46d06m59.18842415s
    dec      : 17d00m23.26250133s
    distance : 19.650620652696077 AU

  Heliocentric, cartesian
    x        : 13.026059371947637 AU
    y        : 13.543854975187806 AU
    z        : 5.747404778310051 AU

  Distance to Earth : 20.636385176873777 AU


## Neptune

  Geocentric
    ra       : 357d04m30.25912968s
    dec      : -2d33m24.96298302s
    distance : 30.67105009955795 AU

  Heliocentric
    ra       : 355d56m45.66281597s
    dec      : -3d04m39.72305339s
    distance : 29.910360622756777 AU

  Heliocentric, cartesian
    x        : 29.792487947312594 AU
    y        : -2.111502508215247 AU
    z        : -1.605892789196556 AU

  Distance to Earth : 30.67105009955795 AU
```

You could use a Python debugger to see what the intermediary steps are, or move around the code (e.g. in VSCode, Spyder or PyCharm) with "Go To Definition" feature.

Comment: Your answer is outstanding! Thank you!

Comment: @noonespecial My pleasure! I always like to play a bit with Astropy. I've updated the answer, BTW, to show both spherical and Cartesian coordinates in the heliocentric frame.

Comment: Way too many significant digits in that answer.

Comment: @Wyck: You're correct. That's the standard representation of Astropy coordinates. I didn't want to make the code more complex than it is.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a short answer to get the ball rolling:

> However, orbital parameters do not indicate where the body was at a specified date and time to calculate current position...

That's absolutely right, you've got the picture correctly. You have two problems every orbital mechanic faces;

1. There is no analytical solution for position as a function of time for any Keplerian orbit except circles.
2. There's all those transformations from a Keplerian orbit in its 2D plane back to the 3D world.

Each of those are addressed in many questions and answers both here in Space SE and in [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/). You can start with answer(s) to [Calculate position of planet on fictitious orbit each day](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/63274/12102) and the links therein, and search further.

If you want to use an ephemeris and a python package, then check out [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield).

And as [PM2Ring points out](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/63456/distance-from-earth-to-another-planet-in-solar-system#comment209398_63456) there is

- https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/
- https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/planets/approx_pos.html

For more resources see [Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/7982) in Astronomy SE.

Comment: This is very helpful answer. Lots of useful insights and resources. Thank you.

Comment: While it is technically true that no analytic solution exists for Kepler's equation, it's very tame numerically. See "Fixed-point iteration" at the end of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation. Why is that at the end? I don't know: the authors seem to want to revel in the difficulty of solving it in other ways.